# Convert a SQL Server Query to C# LINQ having ROW_NUMBER() and OVER

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq, row-number

i need to convert this query to C# LINQ
but i have no idea how start. thank you for your time.

```
SELECT s.TextId, s.Title, s.CategoryId, s.Name, s.DateSent, Row
FROM 
   (SELECT t.TextId, t.Title, t.CategoryId, c.Name, t.DateSent, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.CategoryId ORDER BY t.datesent DESC) AS Row
    FROM Concept_Text t 
    JOIN Concept_Text_Categories c 
      ON t.CategoryId = c.CategoryId 
    JOIN Concept_Text_CategoryToPlugin cp 
      ON c.CategoryId = cp.CategoryId 
    JOIN Concept_Text_Plugins p 
      ON cp.PluginId = p.PluginId
    WHERE p.type = 12 AND (t.IsPublished = 'True') AND (Visible = 'True')
    GROUP BY t.TextId, t.Title, t.CategoryId, c.Name, t.DateSent) s
WHERE Row <=12
```

with help, so far, i got this

```
(from t in Concept_Text
   join c in Concept_Text_Categories on t.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId
   join cp in Concept_Text_CategoryToPlugin on c.CategoryId equals cp.CategoryID
   join p in Concept_Text_Plugins on cp.PluginID equals p.PluginID
   where p.Type == 12 && t.IsPublished && t.Visible
   group cp by new { t.TextId, t.Title, t.CategoryId, c.Name, t.DateSent } into gr
   orderby gr.Key.DateSent descending
   select new
   {
       gr.Key.TextId,
       gr.Key.Title,
       gr.Key.CategoryId,
       gr.Key.Name,
       gr.Key.DateSent
   })
```

the only problem now is the we need to get 12 enteries of each category.

Comment: Usually this is used for pagination. With LINQ, you can use Skip and Take methods. Have you tried anything of these?

Comment: @AdrianIftode, actually i need the 12 most recent entreries for each category, the results are something like this pic [link](http://img252.imageshack.us/img252/8241/stackoverflow.png)

Comment: Can't you force LINQ to use a specific query? I know you can make it call a stored proc. That might be the best way to go for a complex query.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it doesn't answer at all at your question. You might go with @HLGEM's solution.

Comment: i was trying to sent the sql, but it's to long, anyway, tanks for the help, i'm trying to mix the answers.

Comment: Is this LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: I undeleted it.. see what you can do with, compare the generated tsql (edit the question and post your linq)

Comment: @dez can be with Entity Framework as well

Comment: EF has quite different rules with pagination.. but my last update is ok to use with EF also

Comment: In EF you can define a function in you model and map it to ROW_NUMBER()… see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx

Comment: @dez, agree, but how to map partition by? (L2S can map a function also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(from c in Concept_Text_Categories
                            join cp in Concept_Text_CategoryToPlugin
                            on c.CategoryId equals CategoryID
                            join p in Concept_Text_Plugins
                            on PluginID equals p.PluginID
                            where p.Type == 12
                            && c.Enabled
                            && p.Enabled
                            orderby c.Name ascending
                            select new ()
                            {
                                CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
                                Name = c.Name,
                                Materias = (from t in Concept_Text
                                        where t.CategoryId == c.CategoryId
                                        && t.IsPublished
                                        && t.Visible
                                        orderby t.DateSent
                                        select new ()
                                        {
                                            TextId = t.TextId,
                                            Title = t.Title
                                        }).Take(12)
                            })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this:

```
var query = 
(
   from t in Concept_Texts
   join c in Concept_Text_Categories on t.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId
   join cp in Concept_Text_CategoryToPlugin on c.CategoryId equals cp.CategoryId
   join p in Concept_Text_Plugins on cp.CategoryId equals p.CategoryId

   where p.type = 12 && t.IsPublished == "True" AND t.Visible == "True"
   group cp by new {t.TextId, t.Title, t.CategoryId, c.Name, t.DateSent} into gr
   select new {
              gr.Key.TextId, 
              gr.Key.Title, 
              gr.Key.CategoryId, 
              gr.Key.Name, 
              gr.Key.DateSent,
              MinC = gr.Min(gcp=>gcp.CategoryId },
              MaxC = gr.Max(gcp=>gcp.CategoryId }
).Where(c=>c.CategoryId >= c.MinC && c.CategoryId <= c.MaxC)
 .OrderByDescending(c=>c.DateSent)
 .Skip(0).Take(12);
```

Can you test this with LINQ Pad? see what SQL produces?

Comment: you missed a join so i made some changes in the query and there are the result [img](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/8241/stackoverflow.png)

Comment: I'm kind lost at (s.CategoryId BETWEEN MinC AND MaxC). If you get no answer about this, you might with @HLGEM's solution

Comment: look at the edited question, that linq works, but i need now, 12 most recent enteries of each category. As i have 6 categories, then the query must return 72 results, your only returns 12 most recents of all categories.

Comment: so, did it work? don't accept the answer if it didn't work. Someone might come with an idea (other than a view or a stored procedure..)

Comment: almost there, but we are in on the way we only need to improve the last part

i need now, 12 most recent enteries of each category. As i have 6 categories, then the query must return 72 results, your only returns 12 most recents of all categories.